# How does the android system get the current selected View of a spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

I want to extend the `Spinner`-Widget with the functionality that multiple items can be selected. My Problem is the `View` that is shown if the `Spinner`-Widget is closed. I want to replace it with an `TextView` that displays all selected items separated by comma.

My first thought was that the system gets that view from `AbsSpinner.getSelectedView()`, so I overrode this method and returned a `TextView`, but the system still showed the first item, not the `TextView`.

My second thought was that the system gets the `View` with code similar to that one:

```
View v = adapter.getView(getSelectedItemPosition(), null, null);
```

I tried to override `getSelectedItemPosition()` and returned `-1` and in `getView` of the adapter I returned the `TextView` with the selected items if the position is `-1`. Unfortunately this also did not work :-(.

Have you got a solution for my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I want to extend the Spinner-Widget with the functionality that multiple items can be selected* - this doesn't make sense. A `Spinner` as its documentation says(*A view that displays one child at a time and lets the user pick among them*) only selects a child. Trying to change this would would also be bad for the user experience because that would not be a normal flow for a `Spinner`. If you need then make your own view that allows multiple selections.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to make. My Custom `Spinner` shows CheckBoxes on the right-hand side of each item of the spinner. In my opinion that's the best way that does **not** destroy the user experience. But if there is no solution, I have to use a `Button` that uses the Spinner-style and initiates a `AlertDialog` with a list.